Can we represent finitely generated torsion free $\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$ modules as subgroups of matrices?
According to http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.4153, any finitely generated torsion free $\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$-module can be represented as a quotient of $\oplus_{i\in \mathbb Z} \mathbb Z$.

Proposition 2.4.   Assume that $M$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$-module.
There exists a pair $U, B$ of finitely generated abelian groups and monomorphisms $f, g: U \rightarrow B$ such that $M$ is isomorphic to
the infinite free product $$\cdots \oplus_U B \oplus_U B \oplus_U
 \cdots$$ with identical amalgamations $B \stackrel{g}{\leftarrow} U
 \xrightarrow{f} B$;

May I ask if we can represent such modules as subgroup of matrices, if we allow indeterminate variables (for example, subgroup of $\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]^n$)? Any reference would be really appricated.
